# unicode data retrival for data stored in column of data type varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a column named city whose data type is changed from `nvarchar` to `varchar` mistakenly and unicode data stored in this column during this period is present in form like `'%??%'`.I have converted column data type back to `nvarchar` but is there a way to retrieve data values from '???' to the actual value.

```
+----------+
|   City   |
+----------+
|   ???    |
|   ??     |
|   ??     |
|   ??     |
|   ??     |
|   ??     |
+----------+
```

Comment: Do you have backups?

Comment: You lost the extra information required to retrieve the correct values when the data was inserted.  There's no way to "magic it back again" now that it has gone.

Comment: I think it might also be an appropriate time to have a conversation with the person that changed the data type of said column and discuss the implications of their actions; and also review if they should indeed have permissions to have performed said actions.

Comment: thanks for the help, I guess I need to find the data in backups!